# What is the timezone for the start date mentioned in Outlook Mail query?

Tags: api, email, search, timezone, outlook.com

I am looking at the Mail API for Outlook.com:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages#optional-query-parameters

Going deeper in the page chain, I reached this page that lists the valid format for the value of the search parameter:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-Mail-and-People-in-Outlook-com-and-Outlook-on-the-web-for-business-88108edf-028e-4306-b87e-7400bbb40aa7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Clearly calls out that:
IMPORTANT: Date searches must be entered in month/day/year format: MM/DD/YYYY.

But, no place in the document, has it been listed what timezone is going to be used for the query.

I want to poll for new email every 4 hours. But based on this API, I can only scan every day. That may work too, but its too broad. Doesn't tell me what time zone. So I may have to end up scanning two days, when I needed only a few hours.

Does anyone know for sure if this is a UTC based search, or if there is a documented way to specify the timezone ?

I am writing an iOS app and the user timezone may differ based on their location or preferences.